# Enabling HTML in MENU_LOCAL_TASK titles (primary tabs)

Tags: routes

I would like to place a `<br />` tag in my `MENU_LOCAL_TASK` titles so that I can reduce the width of the primary tabs.

It seems that in [theme_menu_local_task](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/theme_menu_local_task/7) the link title is run through `check_plain`, but when I remark this line out only the link title of the active tab responds. All the inactive tab link title are still being sanitized.

Basically, I want to have HTML in my `MENU_LOCAL_TASK` titles - without using any contrib modules.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The key is this `if` construct: `if (!empty($variables['element']['#active']))` with regard to getting the titles of the inactive tabs to respond. My solution was to customize: `theme_menu_local_task`. Perhaps there is a better solution?

```
/**
 * Alter theme_menu_local_task.
 */
function my_theme_menu_local_task($variables) {
  $link = $variables['element']['#link'];
  $link_text = $link['title'];

  if (!empty($variables['element']['#active'])) {
    // Add text to indicate active tab for non-visual users.
    $active = '<span class="element-invisible">' . t('(active tab)') . '</span>';

    // If the link does not contain HTML already, check_plain() it now.
    // After we set 'html'=TRUE the link will not be sanitized by l().
    if (empty($link['localized_options']['html'])) {
      if (arg(0) != 'my-page') { // ** ADDED **
        $link['title'] = check_plain($link['title']);
      } // ** ADDED **
    }
    $link['localized_options']['html'] = TRUE;
    $link_text = t('!local-task-title!active', array('!local-task-title' => $link['title'], '!active' => $active));
  }

  if (arg(0) == 'my-page') { // ** ADDED **
    $link['localized_options']['html'] = TRUE; // ** ADDED **
  } // ** ADDED **

  return '<li' . (!empty($variables['element']['#active']) ? ' class="active"' : '') . '>' . l($link_text, $link['href'], $link['localized_options']) . "</li>\n";
}
```